# Is it incorrect to say 'I have encountered him through that film' even if the time is unspecified/unimportant?

Tags: present-perfect

A native has pointed out to me that I should use 'I encountered him/her/it through something', but couldn't quite explain why. What's the exact reason something like 'I've encountered it before/many times/etc' is okay, but 'I've encountered it through something' sounds bad?

Comment: It's just not idiomatic to say "encountered X *through* Y".  But you didn't tell us what you are trying to say!  What do you mean when you say "I encountered it *through* something"?

Comment: @stangdon sorta like 'meeting someone through someone else', like that person introduced you to them. in this case, i encountered a poem through a film i watched and was just talking about it and said 'a poem that ive encountered through this film' and they corrected me. im more interested in knowing about the present perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That native speaker was right: simple past is correct, and present perfect is incorrect.

There's two meanings of "encounter" here, which is causing the confusion. The one used in your first example sentence means something like "*to be **first** introduced to*" someone/something. If you encounter someone through a movie, it means you are first introduced to some actor or character through that movie. *It just happens once*.

The other meaning of "encounter" which appears in your second example means something like, "bump into" or "see" or "come across". *It can happen again and again*. This would apply to a concept or situation that happens over and over, and presumably will happen again.

As you may know, *present perfect* refers to past events *without specifying a finished past time*, OR to events that started in the past and *continue to the present*. In the case of your first sentence, however, the event is in the past, it won't happen again, and the finished past time when it happened is given: "through that film". The implied time is "when I watched that film".

If you drop that phrase, the sentence becomes correct with present perfect:

> I have encountered that actor.

Comment: thanks! i always take my native friends' word for it, but i also like having a clear explanation so as to avoid any future mistakes.

Comment: @JamesCampbell Glad I could help. FWIW, we say "native speaker", not "native". A "native" is someone who is originally from some place, and has nothing to do with language. In North America, "native" particularly refers to people whose ancestry in that place goes back to before Europeans came.

Comment: oh yeah, mb. generally when talking to my wife who's a native speaker herself, i say just 'native' to mean native speaker, but i can't just throw that word around other people. thanks for reminding me!

Comment: BTW, on this site, if you like an answer, you can upvote it, and if you think an answer fully satisfies your question, you can give it a check mark. Not begging, just informing ;)

Comment: oh, mb, i didnt know. im totally new to the site. gotta have some rep to upvote, but ive accepted ur answer, so at least that :) thanks for the help!